# Typescript - conditional property based on another property

Tags: typescript

When defining a type, can we make one property required based on another property?

An example is:

```
type Parent = {
  children?: Child[];
  childrenIdSequence: string[]; // Only make this required when `children` is given
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be achieved using a union type:

```js
type Parent = {
  children: Child[],
  childrenIdSequence: string[]
} | {
  children: undefined
}
```

This means a `Parent` either has a `children` array and a `childrenIdSequence` array, or its `children` property is undefined and it is not guaranteed to have a `childrenIdSequence` array. The type can be control-flow narrowed by testing the `children` property:

```js
function test(p: Parent): void {
    if(p.children) {
        // p: { children: Child[], childrenIdSequence: string[] }, so OK
        console.log(p.childrenIdSequence);
    } else {
        // p: { children: undefined }, so type error
        console.log(p.childrenIdSequence);
    }
}
```

However, there is a bit of a downside: the `children` property is required even if you want it to be undefined. You have to explicitly write a literal like `{ children: undefined }` instead of just `{}`, otherwise it won't be of type `Parent`.

If you try declaring the type with `children?: undefined` as an optional property, then the union won't work because one branch is a structural subtype of the other, and the type in the function will be uselessly narrowed to `p: never`.