# typescript interface, if one, other required

Tags: typescript, types

It's possible to create an interface with multiples properties, and if one of these is use, an other is also required ?

For example :

```
interface MyProps {
  onPressAll: () => void;
  icon?: ImageSourcePropType;
  onPressIcon?: () => void;
}
```

What I want is: if **icon** is set, then **onPressIcon** is required (or vice versa), else no one should be used.

for example, when I call my component:

```
<MyComponent
   onPressAll={() => {}}
   icon={myIcon}
/>
// This should return an error because onPressIcon is missing

<MyComponent
   onPressAll={() => {}}
   onPressIcon={() => {}}
/>
// This should return an error because icon is missing



<MyComponent
   onPressAll={() => {}}
/>
// Good

<MyComponent
   onPressAll={() => {}}
   onPressIcon={() => {}}
   icon={myIcon}
/>
// Good
```

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350724/typescript-conditional-property-based-on-another-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with an interface. You need to use a union:

```
type MyPropsCommon = {
  onPressAll: () => void;
} 
type MyProps = MyPropsCommon & (
    | { icon?: undefined, onPressIcon?: undefined}
    | {
        icon: ImageSourcePropType;
        onPressIcon: () => void;
    })
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgtgQwOYQMoHsCuAnAxhABW3TABVxoBeKAZ2GwEsA7JAKFEigFkQiSaAwujhx0TKNQDerKFDFEINGgEEANqoBcUABQBKCQD4oAN3QMAJgG5WAXyjsK3XsTA0JTvq6EixUAGQ6MrJQAD5QklAMuGIA-FqYTOYQAGbMEOYANHJMCkow0UxxUAlJqUzpNkGyYdLBdZEFWvDIaFh4hC7kkNb1wfLYijT5Ylp6hiZmVlVQNrqsrAD0C+gA1qyqEMAmAIxaPJ5uUtP9g2qaOvqURpKVlYsLUACi2MTYsp4Q2KBQAOQneQUfpE3HAGEpmGwNltjAAmPbOfjuWp9HIDJRnUaXa42DLTKIjKAAIkJtnmS1W602JgAzPCDkjjqjTupMeMbri6vimFpiRyUbkho0LmycbYgA)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Discriminating Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).

```
interface PropsWithIcons {
  onPressAll: () => void;
  hasIcon: true
  icon: ImageSourcePropType;
  onPressIcon: () => void;
}

interface PropsWithoutIcons {
  hasIcon: false
  onPressAll: () => void;
}

type MyProps = PropsWithIcons | PropsWithoutIcons

var obj: MyProps = {} as MyProps

if (obj.hasIcon) {
  console.log(obj.icon, obj.onPressIcon)
}
else {
  console.log(obj.icon, obj.onPressIcon) // errors
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOB1YMACwEkEMQdkBvAKGWQvQhxwEEAbDgLmQAoAlMgC8APmQA3DMAAmAbnrIicHGQq8wUAK4RFwciF4kAtnADmEAMoYtUJOmwAVAJ5YIChkygtVB3oJFxKVkFAF9aWlBIWEQUB1wCYhswNUoaRWVfdWR4DhxdTxBmVk4efiExSWl5WnDaMFcUAFlneKphNEwEwlIDKgAfTux8HuTUnAiJOChGACMAK14WtpEaUOQVZGWuiciYfgwFgDpM1KE6Bj6MDggjjgwzPkP5o-0KABo5l68fM9raCB5FAXZBXG53B5PY5vECfZ5HH6sM7IAD0KOQ0EwUAm4SAA)

Answer (score 0):

You could just extend interfaces:

```
interface MyCommonProps
{
    onPressAll: () => void;
}

interface MyIconProps extends MyCommonProps
{
    icon: ImageSourcePropType;
    onPressIcon: () => void;
}
```

You can also combine types so that all properties are required:

```
interface MyOtherProps 
{
    other: number;
}

type MyProps = MyIconProps & MyOtherProps;
```

Choose what fits your purpose.